# How to add security to a PDF file using LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, pdf

How can we add security to a [PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) file created using [LibreOffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice)?

I want to create PDF files which cannot be edited and that is the reason for asking this question.

Comment: just the change the file permissions.

Comment: generally pdf files cannot be edited

Comment: @avinash raj how to change the permission

Comment: i should run this command in the terminal?

Comment: @AvinashRaj that will only secure the file locally, i.e. if you send it in e-mail, it loses the "protection".

Comment: @AvinashRaj he said "pdf files which cannot be edited". A PDF file with 700 permissions is not "pdf files which cannot be edited". It *can* be edited.

Comment: Nobody pointing out this kind of "protection" is actually useless?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're looking for setting security within the PDF itself, LibreOffice can do so. Use the `Export as PDF` option from the `File` menu. The resulting dialog has a tab named 'Security`:
[image: 'Export as PDF' dilalog box]

For command line conversion, the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/openoffice.1.html) suggest that convert can use the options set in the Writer's *Export as PDF* dialog. So I suppose you could set it once in an instance of Writer, close it, and then use the `--convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export` option. I think similar filters may be available for Draw and others as well, but I'm not sure. See http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/?answer=6292#post-id-6292 for more information on how to look up filters.

Comment: is there a way to set these permissions using command line tool from libre office along with the convert-to option

Comment: @deadman The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/openoffice.1.html) suggest that convert can use the options set in the Writer's *Export as PDF* dialog. So I suppose you could set it once in an instance of Writer, and then use the `--convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export` option. I think similar filters may be available for Draw and others as well, but I'm not sure. See http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/?answer=6292#post-id-6292 for more information on how to look up filters.