# LibreOffice Writer - export as PDF - disable copying of content

Tags: password, libreoffice, pdf, evince

In LibreOffice Writer Version: 5.1.6.2 - export as PDF, I try to disable copying the content.

I.e. I don't want people to open the PDF file with a PDF viewer application and copy the content (text) to the clipboard.

I follow the [instructions in an older answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/486639/274982).

I set a "permission password".

Then I uncheck "Enable copying of content".

Then I export as PDF.

But then I open the PDF with [Evince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evince) version 3.18.2 and can copy the content like a boss.

Is it a bug?

Comment: It's a feature. If you can read something you can copy it. [Evince doesn't bother checking DRM features](https://superuser.com/questions/767617/disable-drm-in-evince).

Comment: A lot of Linux PDF viewers don't think much of DRM, makes it nice when someone sends you an Office protected document *insert Nope gif*

Comment: Are there ways then to make the content less easy to copy other than converting it to image (but then I lose features like clickable links)

Comment: Yes - but why? If the user wants they can copy the content if they can view it. No matter what you try to do.

Comment: They could always retype it, or run through OCR, even if I converted it to an image. I would like to prevent it from them to easily copy it by select all & copy. Most of them will not go any further since they are technologically challenged.

Comment: @rapt: Easy! Tell them to use only PDF viewers that respect DRM settings, e. g. Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stop your text from being copied, the only way is to first turn them into images and then turn them back in PDF. It's easy:

1. you need a PDF editor like Adobe Acrobat or in Ubuntu, nothing works better than [Master PDF Editor](https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/). Open your PDF file with it and go to:

   > File> Export to> Images

then select the format (like jpg) and directory.

2. Open the terminal and go to the directory you saved the images and type:

   ```
   convert *.jpg output.pdf
   ```

There you have a perfect PDF!

Answer (score 2):

There really is no way to accomplish what you are requesting. All sales mumbo-jumbo aside, there's nothing you can do with a commercial product as mentioned elsewhere that you can't do with open source tools such as `gimp` , etc. And as you mention [in your own comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001716/libreoffice-writer-export-as-pdf-disable-copying-of-content/1001745#comment1619996_1001716) there is **always** a workaround. Whether that be an existing tool such as [vidarlo mentions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001716/libreoffice-writer-export-as-pdf-disable-copying-of-content/1001745#comment1619983_1001716) or simply running OCR over the document. Seeing as how [the PDF specification](https://www.iso.org/standard/63534.html) doesn't specify specific methods, developers are free to provide whatever functions they feel are useful. Securing your text doesn't appear to be a priority for every PDF processor across all platforms.